# How to disable previous date unselectable in full calendar pluggin

Tags: php, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm using [https://fullcalendar.io/][1]

[1]: https://fullcalendar.io/ in my project, I need to disable previous date and unselectable,
I try below code:but I don't know how to disable previous date...

```
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            select: function (start, end, allDay) {

            var check = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start,'yyyy-MM-dd');
            var today = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(new Date(),'yyyy-MM-dd');
            if(check < today)
            {  
                alert('disabled');
            }
            else
            {

            var seleted_cells = parseInt($("#day_selected").text());
            seleted_cells = seleted_cells + 1;                          
            $("#day_selected").text(seleted_cells);
            }              

        },
```

Anyone please help...

Answer (score 0):

Just pass current date in the line -> `start: ''`. Replace your calender `id`, Some what like this

```
// constrain to an open-ended range
$('#calendar2').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'month',
    validRange: {
        start: '2017-05-01'
    }
});
```

Comment: defaultView: 'month',
   visibleRange: {
          start: '2017-05-19',
          end: '2017-05-09'
      }

Comment: visibleRange Works fine with defaultView: 'agenda' bot not with 'month'.

Comment: ok, is it possible to set the calendar view to the next month?

Comment: var Year = new Date().getFullYear();
  var month = new Date().getMonth();
  month = month+1;
  $('#day_selected').fullCalendar({
    defaultDate: new Date(Year, month, 1)
  });